# the expression inside th:field gives Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name error

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am trying to create table that can be saved as a form and I am Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'rows[0]' available as request attribute. I can see the problem is from rows used inside th:field but can figure out how to fix it

Below is the code sample

```
//Entity class
public class TimeTable {
        @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Integer id;

    String day;
    
    @Column(name="start_time")
    String startTime;
    
    @Column(name = "end_time")
    String endTime;

}
```

```
//controller class
    @GetMapping("/timetable/new")
    public String newTimetable(Model model) {
        
        List<TimeTable> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        rows.add(new TimeTable("Monday", "", ""));
        rows.add(new TimeTable("Tuesday", "", ""));
        rows.add(new TimeTable("Wednesday", "", ""));
        rows.add(new TimeTable("Thusday", "", ""));
        rows.add(new TimeTable("Friday", "", ""));
        rows.add(new TimeTable("Saturday", "", ""));
        rows.add(new TimeTable("Sunday", "", ""));
        
        //model.addAttribute("timetableObject", new TimeTable());
        model.addAttribute("rows", rows);
        
        return "timetable/timetable_new";
    }
```

```
<form th:action="@{/timetable/save}" method="post" >
                <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive-sm align-middle" id="tableRefresh">
                    <thead class=" text-center">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Day</th>
                            <th scope="col">Start Time</th>
                            <th scope="col">End Time</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                            <tr th:each="row, rowStat : ${rows}">
                                <td>[[${row.day}]]</td>
                                <td>
                                    <input type="text" name="startTime"  th:field="*{rows[__${rowStat.index}__].startTime}" class="form-control">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            <button type="submit" class="form-control btn btn-outline-success">Save</button>
            </form>
```

picture of what I am trying to achieve

[image: picture of what i am trying to achieve]

generated error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'rows[0]' available as request attribute
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:153)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.getBindStatus(RequestContext.java:926)
at org.thymeleaf.spring6.context.webmvc.SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.getBindStatus(SpringWebMvcThymeleafRequestContext.java:232)
at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatusFromParsedExpression(FieldUtils.java:306)
at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:253)
at org.thymeleaf.spring6.util.FieldUtils.getBindStatus(FieldUtils.java:227)
at org.thymeleaf.spring6.processor.AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractSpringFieldTagProcessor.java:174)
at org.thymeleaf.processor.element.AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.doProcess(AbstractAttributeTagProcessor.java:74)
... 116 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `th:field`, then you need to add a model attribute to your model and set it as the `th:object` of your `<form />`.  Since you are using a variable named `rows`, your th:object should look like this:

```
public class TimeTableForm {
    private List<TimeTable> rows;

    public void setRows(List<TimeTable> rows) {
        this.rows = rows;
    }

    public List<TimeTable> getRows() {
        return rows;
    }
}
```

it must be added to your model in your controller:

```
TimeTableForm form = new TimeTableForm();
form.setRows(rows);
model.addAttribute("timeTableForm", timeTableForm);
```

and your form must be updated to reflect the new object:

```
<form th:action="@{/timetable/save}" th:object="timeTableForm" method="post">
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but I want to ask how am I going to save it.  I tried something like this but it didn't work @PostMapping("/timetable/save")
 public String saveTimetable(@ModelAttribute("rows") List<TimeTable> rows) {
  
  for (TimeTable row : rows) {
   TimeTable timetableForm = new TimeTable(row.getDay(), row.getStartTime(), row.getEndTime(), row.getRoomNumber());
   timeTableService.saveTimeTable(timetableForm);
  }
  
  return "redirect:/timetable";
 }

Comment: It should be `public String saveTimetable(@ModelAttribute("timeTableForm") TimeTableForm timetableForm` -- you can't use a List as a backing object.  Just submit and use the form object.

Comment: That will affect the saveTimeTable service method which is of type TimeTable object. 
My service method is like this  public TimeTable saveTimeTable (TimeTable timetable ) {
        return timeTableRepo.save(timetable );
    }

Comment: This shouldn't change anything with your service, because you still have access to the rows via `timetableForm.getRows()` -- which was the way you were saving before right? Why does that change?

Comment: please kindly check this to understand what I am saying https://github.com/ecclesiastes12/EccSchoolSystem/tree/TimeTable/SchoolManagementSystemWebParent/SchoolManagementSystemBackEnd/src/main/java/com/sch/admin/TimeTable